# Creating a table in splunk with trends

Tags: time, splunk

I'd like to create a table like the following columns:

server - event count - event count last period

what do I mean by that?

I have to do a count by of the events, and this is trivial.

```
base query | stats count as events by source
```

now i have a selector that let me select the period (the classic splunk time selector).

what i need is the following:
if the selector is "last week" i need to count in the first column the events of the last week and in the second column the events of the week before that

if the selector is "last mount" i need to count in the first column the events of the last mount and in the second column the events of the mount before that

etc...

Id like to do that without messing with html, xml or any other language. I'd like, if possible, a plain splunk search.

Thanks a lot.

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial solution because involves changing variables to change the time span.

```
BASE SEARCH earliest=-14d latest=now 
| eval when=if(_time>relative_time(now(), "-7d@d"), "Current_Week", "Prev_Week") 
| stats count as events by  source when 
| chart sum(events) by source, when 
| eval perc = (Current_Week-Prev_Week)/Prev_Week
| eval trend = case(perc < -0.3, "low", (perc >= -0.3 and perc <= 0.3 ), "madium", perc > 0.3, "high")
| table source, Current_Week, Prev_Week, perc, trend
```